# Access headers from POST request in expressjs nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm trying to access timezone header requested through post request. I am able to access it in app.js but can not access it in request path file.

`app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var apiRoutes = express.Router();
var apiHeader = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
server = require('http').createServer(app);
var customer = require(__dirname + "/bin/customer.js");
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'timezone');   
    next();
});

apiHeader.use(function(req, res, next) {

    var timezone = req.body.timezone || req.query.timezone || req.headers['timezone'];
   next();
    }
})
app.use('/', apiHeader);

app.post('/api/add/addcalllog', customer.addcalllog);
```

`customer.js`

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
exports.addcalllog = function(req, res) {
 console.log(timezone);
}
```

Comment: Are you importing `customer.js` in `app.js` anywhere?

Comment: @Aron Yes question edited.

Comment: Based off my understanding of the scope of `var timezone` as illustrated in your code, shouldn't you have to check `req.headers` again in your `customer.js` file? I'm not seeing how the scope of `timezone` is accessible there, unless I missed something

Comment: Body, query and headers? Oh my... That's gonna be a pain in the ass. Stick to body and use headers for small things.

Comment: Just call req.timezone inside addcalllog

Answer (score -1):

You can attach timezone to a new object on the request that will be accessible to the route after the next().

```
 req.timezone = //your stuff here
```

But I strongly urge you to pick one data exchange method not three.